# Android - Nodejs Socket Connection failed, Have no other message

Tags: node.js, kotlin

my nodes code (express, socket.io)

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
 
app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));
 
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
 
// views is directory for all template files
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
 
//before connected
console.log("outside io");
 
io.on('connection', function(socket){
 
  //login, appear 2 below
  console.log('User Conncetion');
 
  socket.on('connect user', function(user){
    console.log("Connected user ");
    socket.join(user['roomName']);
    console.log("roomName : ",user['roomName']);
    console.log("state : ",socket.adapter.rooms);
    io.emit('connect user', user);
  });
 
 
  //send message, logging in server this
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    console.log("Message " + msg['message']);
    console.log("보내는 아이디 : ",msg['roomName']);
    io.to(msg['roomName']).emit('chat message', msg);
  });
});
 
//when connected server, print port number
http.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Node app is running on port', app.get('port'));
});
```

my android code

```
//Socket variables
var mSocket: Socket = IO.socket("http://13.124.252.17:5000")
```

```
//Socket setting
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            hasConnection = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("hasConnection")
        }

        //Connect to server
        if (!hasConnection) {

            //Generate room name
            var rnds = (0..20000).random()
            roomName = "room_" + rnds

            //Connect
            connect(roomName)

        }
```

```
private fun connect(room: String) {

        //Connect
        mSocket.connect()

        //Attach callbacks
        mSocket.on("connect user", onNewUser)
        mSocket.on("chat message", onNewMessage)
        mSocket.on("user left", onUserLeft)
        mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, onConnect)
        mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_DISCONNECT, onDisconnect)
        mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR, onConnectError)
        mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, onConnectTimeout)

        //Make json form
        val jsonObject = JSONObject()

        try {

            jsonObject.put("uuid", uuid)
            jsonObject.put("roomName", room)

            //Send message
            mSocket.emit("connect user", jsonObject)

        } catch (e: JSONException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

    }
```

I just get 2 Error message, one is "io.socket.engineio.client.EngineIOException: server error" and my tag "Connect Error"

but node.js server Works well with "Node app is running on port 5000"
I import io.socket.client.IO, io.socket.client.Socket, io.socket.emitter.Emitter

libraries for socket transport and I use io.socket:socket.io-client:1.0.0

I use AWS, Security groups for "Custom TCP:5000" and android internet permission is already sat..